# Save and Restore Row Selections in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

The problem is fairly straightforward. My datagrid is filled from my ItemSource (bindingList) which is basically a list of objects filled with strings.

In this certain part of my code I need to update my bindingList.
Unfortunately when it is updated all user row selections made in the DataGrid dissappear.

This is an inconvenience to the user that I would like to remedy. So that when the user clicks the button that results in the bindingList to update, the selections are saved in case the user wants to make further changes.

Code Right Now:

```
//Save DataGrid Row Selections
bindingList[1] = (new ItemClass() { columnnumber = colonum, xcoord = xpos, ycoord = ypos, description = descrip });
dataGrid.ItemSource = bindingList;
//Restore DataGrid Row Selections
```

EDIT:
Wider scope as requested:

```
private void Y_Incre_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        string colonum;
        string xpos;
        string ypos;
        string descrip;

        for (int i = 0; i < bindingList.Count; i++)
        {
            int selectionIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;

            if (selectionIndex > -1)
            {
                var curItem = bindingList[selectionIndex];
                int yNum = int.Parse(curItem.ycoord);
                int yNum2 = (yNum + 10);
                colonum = curItem.columnnumber;
                xpos = curItem.xcoord;
                ypos = yNum2.ToString();
                descrip = curItem.description;

                //Save DataGrid Row Selections
                bindingList[selectionIndex] = (new ItemClass() { columnnumber = colonum, xcoord = xpos, ycoord = ypos, description = descrip });
                //Restore DataGrid Row Selections
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Rows Selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show a little more code please (surrounding 15 lines or so)

Comment: If you used proper XAML binding to set your ItemSource to an ObservableCollection, then insert/delete items into the ObservableCollection (instead of replacing the collection) then you might achieve what you want.

Comment: I am not inserting or deleting items, simply updating the selected item (by replacing it). Is that possibly done differently in an ObservableCollection?

Comment: "Updating" the selected item by *replacing* it is **not** updating - it is replacing. Therefore it is correct for the item in the selected list to be removed - it no longer exists. If you want to update then merge your changes into the existing item, or (more kludgy) insert the new item at the same index as the old item, remove the old item, and set the new item to selected.

Comment: I see your point. Can you provide an example for merging?

Comment: Is the "bindinglist" an ObservableCollection<T> or List<T>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working store the row indices of the selected items before they are replaced, and then reselect those records after the "replace" operation is complete. Also, have a look at [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx) example.

```
private void Y_Incre_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        // Save DataGrid Row Selections
        List<int> selectedRowIndexList = new List<int>();
        foreach (object item in dataGrid.SelectedItems)
        {
            selectedRowIndexList.Add(dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(item));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bindingList.Count; i++)
        {
            int selectionIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;

            if (selectionIndex > -1)
            {
                ItemClass curItem = bindingList[selectionIndex];

                int yNum = int.Parse(curItem.ycoord);

                int yNum2 = yNum + 10;

                string colonum = curItem.columnnumber;
                string xpos = curItem.xcoord;
                string ypos = yNum2.ToString();
                string descrip = curItem.description;

                bindingList[selectionIndex] = new ItemClass { columnnumber = colonum, xcoord = xpos, ycoord = ypos, description = descrip };
            }
        }

        // Restore DataGrid Row Selections
        dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();
        foreach (int rowIndex in selectedRowIndexList)
        {
            if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex > dataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is an invalid row index.", rowIndex));

            object item = dataGrid.Items[rowIndex];
            dataGrid.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Rows Selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. The part I got hitched on was I did not know SelectedItems had an Add member. Thank you!